# Time complexity and Gauss Sum Identity in Java Nested Loops

Tags: java, time-complexity

```
public static int[] intSum(int[] arr2) {
  int[] arr1 = new int[arr2.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      arr1[i] += arr2[j];
     }
  }
  return arr1;
}
```

Given the method, we were told that the inner loop can be summarized using Gauss's sum identity, and as such, the complexity in polynomial form is

`T(n) = c_0 + c_1 * n + c_2 * n + (1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)) * c_3`

=> `T(n) = c_0 + n * c_1 * n * c_2 * (n(n+1))/2 * c_3`

I don't really understand this calculation. I get that `c_1 * n` is the array initialization which is `O(n)` in Java, and that `c_2 * n` would be the outer loop, but how does the sum up from `1` to `n-1` work here and how is that related to the inner loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the syntax errors in your code snippet, the inner loop runs from `0` to `i`, where `i` increases each time the `for` is executed again. This gives the sum `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n`.

Now this sum was calculated by the young Gauss in the following way (for even n, but a similar construction works for odd n):

```
1 + n     = n+1
2 + (n-1) = n+1
3 + (n-2) = n+1
...
n/2 + n/2+1 = n+1
```

So in total there are n/2 lines with a sum of n+1 each. This gives the result n*(n+1)/2

Comment: Thanks for the little explanation regarding Gauss's identity, I'm aware of it, I just didn't really understand the calculation for the inner loop (sum of 0 to n), but it's clear now. Thanks Henry! PS: corrected syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops and the code from CPS 150 Lab Project 19 (a childish sum) to produce the output below.  The outer loop control variable can be used to help display the output the inner loop.

The sum of positive integers from 1 to 1 is 1
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 2 is 3
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 3 is 6
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 4 is 10
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 5 is 15
... output for integers 16 to 99
The sum of positive integers from 1 to 100 is 5050

Because we already have a program that computes 1 + 2 + ... + n for any positive integer n, we can embed that code in a second outer loop that loops 100 times.  The outer loop control variable can be used to control the number of times we loop and more importantly, it can be used to control the upper limit of the inner computation.